# Maui label text doesn't update (MVVM)

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm trying to show changing values on MainPage, but it doesn't update the values, unless i change something in the xaml.

In the mainViewModel i've got a double, which i'm changing on a loop.

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private double price;
..
    [RelayCommand]
    void count()
    {
        price++; // <- This is field price and not the property Price
    }
```

in the MainPage.xaml, i have a label i'd like to change

```
<Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='Price: = {0:F2}'}"/>
```

I tought [NotifyPropertyChangedRecipients] might help, but it gives me an error MVVMTK0022.

Comment: Could you show more of the relevant code? Where do you update the price? Where are you setting the `BindingContext`? How familiar are you with  MAUI (or Xamarin.Forms) and MVVM in C#? I'm asking, because MVVM Code Generation is an advanced topic and it is useful to know how properties work without the automatic generation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

Comment: Most likely you are updating the field price and not the property Price. But without seeing more code it’s impossible to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk how to mark it as answer, but Jason pointed at the problem:
"Most likely you are updating the field price and not the property Price."